# Why should os.path.join be used for relative paths?

Tags: python

I have a project which has several directories: Projects, Settings, Resources. What is the best practice for opening files within these directories.

Right now I'm doing:

```py
with open(f'./Projects/{project_name}/project.txt', 'r') as f:
    ...
```

I've seen a lot of people recommend something like this:

```py
projects_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
project_path = os.path.join(projects_path, f'{project_name}/project.txt')
with open(project_path, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

What are the benefits of using the second method over the first? What is the best practice?

Comment: Your first method is dependent on the runtime working directory of your python process. The absolute path of `./Projects` will change if the python process is run from different locations. The second method (using `__file__`) is invariant to the starting location of the process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really the second snippet should be

```
os.path.join(projects_path, project_name, ‘projects.txt’)
```

What’s the benefit? Portability. Your code can more easily run on different operating systems, since windows paths are completely different from *nix paths, but this snippet will still work on both.

This depends on if you *need* your code to be truly cross-platform.

Also, the absolute path allows your code to work regardless of where it’s installed or where it’s running. The current working directory might not have a “Projects” folder because it’s been executed as a shell script living in some /usr/local/bin folder.

In general, hard-coding any relative paths will yield fragile code, because now you require instructions like “this needs to be installed in (specific directory).” Robust code is always better than fragile code.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason most people would recommend this is if you are accessing a lot of files with the same root folder (i.e. projects_path) so you do not have to type it each time. The latter is the best practice.

Comment: No there are definitely more reasons. Not having to worry about duplicate separators for example is very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.join` abstracts you from the differences between operating systems.

Using os.path.* you can run your code without worrying about the OS.